# Unable to open hint directory

Tags: java, cassandra

In an unspecified cycle in the server where Cassandra is installed, the hint folder is deleted by itself, which prevents connection to Cassandra. The log of occurrence is as follows.

```
[2020-03-01 10:08:17,045] [STORAGE] [INFO] [CompactionExecutor:298]  AutoSavingCache.java:404 - Saved KeyCache (100 items) in 7 ms
[2020-03-01 10:09:05,880] [STORAGE] [INFO] [IndexSummaryManager:1]  IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:84 - Redistributing index summaries
[2020-03-01 11:09:05,884] [STORAGE] [INFO] [IndexSummaryManager:1]  IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:84 - Redistributing index summaries
[2020-03-01 11:25:31,759] [STORAGE] [WARN] [HintsWriteExecutor:1]  NativeLibrary.java:316 - open(/tmp/cassandra/hints, O_RDONLY) failed, errno (2).
[2020-03-01 11:25:31,759] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [HintsWriteExecutor:1]  HintsCatalog.java:166 - Unable to open directory /tmp/cassandra/hints
[2020-03-01 11:25:31,761] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [HintsWriteExecutor:1]  StorageService.java:397 - Stopping gossiper
[2020-03-01 11:25:31,761] [STORAGE] [WARN] [HintsWriteExecutor:1]  StorageService.java:307 - Stopping gossip by operator request
[2020-03-01 11:25:31,761] [STORAGE] [INFO] [HintsWriteExecutor:1]  Gossiper.java:1801 - Announcing shutdown
[2020-03-01 11:25:31,762] [STORAGE] [INFO] [HintsWriteExecutor:1]  StorageService.java:2498 - Node 192.168.0.50:7000 state jump to shutdown
[2020-03-01 11:25:31,763] [STORAGE] [INFO] [HintsWriteExecutor:1]  StorageService.java:2498 - Node 192.168.0.50:7000 state jump to shutdown
[2020-03-01 11:25:33,765] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [HintsWriteExecutor:1]  StorageService.java:402 - Stopping native transport
[2020-03-01 11:25:33,768] [STORAGE] [INFO] [HintsWriteExecutor:1]  Server.java:213 - Stop listening for CQL clients
[2020-03-01 11:25:33,771] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [HintsWriteExecutor:1]  CassandraDaemon.java:442 - Exception in thread Thread[HintsWriteExecutor:1,5,main]
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.io.IOException: Unable to open hint directory /tmp/cassandra/hints
    at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsCatalog.fsyncDirectory(HintsCatalog.java:167)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriteExecutor$FsyncWritersTask.run(HintsWriteExecutor.java:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open hint directory /tmp/cassandra/hints
    ... 8 common frames omitted
[2020-03-01 11:25:33,771] [STORAGE] [ERROR] [BatchlogTasks:1]  CassandraDaemon.java:442 - Exception in thread Thread[BatchlogTasks:1,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: FSWriteError in /tmp/cassandra/hints
    at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriteExecutor.fsyncWritersBlockingly(HintsWriteExecutor.java:107)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsService.flushAndFsyncBlockingly(HintsService.java:200)
    at org.apache.cassandra.batchlog.BatchlogManager.processBatchlogEntries(BatchlogManager.java:313)
    at org.apache.cassandra.batchlog.BatchlogManager.replayFailedBatches(BatchlogManager.java:226)
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$UncomplainingRunnable.run(DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:118)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: FSWriteError in /tmp/cassandra/hints
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriteExecutor.fsyncWritersBlockingly(HintsWriteExecutor.java:103)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.io.IOException: Unable to open hint directory /tmp/cassandra/hints
    at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsCatalog.fsyncDirectory(HintsCatalog.java:167)
    at org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsWriteExecutor$FsyncWritersTask.run(HintsWriteExecutor.java:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open hint directory /tmp/cassandra/hints
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

This occurs in Cassandra db, which is used in the web system based on Spring Framework, and cannot be connected unless it is restarted.
In the Spring Framework, scheduling of migrating data from another RDB to Cassandra is executed periodically, and the scheduler is executed every day. Also, the execution time is midnight time.

I was wondering if there was a case where the hints folder was deleted from Cassandra itself, and if there is a way to determine what the cause is, if that happens.

cassandra version is cassandra-4.0-snapshot.

Comment: Have you checked any permission or user issue on that directory ?

Comment: Relying on a **pre-alpha snapshot** of 4.0 as a part of your nightly batch ecosystem is not only ill-advised, it's also a bit foolish.  If the permissions on that directory are fine, try upgrading to the latest alpha release (it's not even in beta yet) to get all the latest bug fixes.

Comment: @LetsNoSQL The permission for the hints folder path has been changed to 777, and the status is being monitored. There is no problem for about a week, but it is expected that we will have to watch the progress further. But can this permission conflict occur even when Cassandra is run as the root account?

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for your advice. We will also check whether it is possible to shoot issues using the latest version.

Comment: @enceAudi  Okay, Its good if there is no issue now. No conflict as its a folder only.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to the server OS (CentOS 7 version). Causes were not recorded in Cassandra's log because folders and files that are not used for more than 10 days in the temp folder delete among the crontab executed as daily on the OS.

It may be different depending on OS type and version, but in CentOS 7 version, deletion exception can be set among temp folders as shown below.

`vim /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf`

Add the phrase below to solve it.

`x /tmp/folder_to_except`